# ListView wont refresh or update in C# Forms application

Tags: c#, forms, listview, refresh

I am trying to write a simple C# password saver utility in MS Visual Studios. I have a listView in formA and I want to use formB to add a new item to the list.

FormB calls forceAdd which is a member of formA. forceAdd then updates the data set and attempts to refresh the listView by calling populateList().

The problem is that the listView does not reflect the changes until I call my populateList() function by a button or check box in formA.

For example, I can call populateList() 50 times in my code to no avail, but as soon as I call it from a button on formA it works.

(DieselPass = fromA, newForm = FormB, newForm::Save calls forceAdd, formA::new opens newForm)

(when i wire the formA::Edit... button up to populate and click it after save, the listView updates)

I'm a new user... this image explains it:
http://i50.tinypic.com/wk6bys.jpg

```
    public void forceAdd(String a, String u, String p)
    {
        accountsDataSet.tblAccounts.AddtblAccountsRow(a, u, p);
        tblAccountsTableAdapter.Update(accountsDataSet.tblAccounts);
        populateList();
    }

    private void populateList()
    {
        //make sure data set is up to date
        this.tblAccountsTableAdapter.Fill(this.accountsDataSet.tblAccounts);
        //clear existing items
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < accountsDataSet.tblAccounts.Count; i++)
        {
            String[] wtf;
            if (maskPasswords)
                wtf = new string[] { accountsDataSet.tblAccounts[i].Account, accountsDataSet.tblAccounts[i].Username };
            else
                wtf = new string[] { accountsDataSet.tblAccounts[i].Account, accountsDataSet.tblAccounts[i].Username, accountsDataSet.tblAccounts[i].Password };
            lvi = new ListViewItem(wtf);
            Console.WriteLine(lvi.ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
    }
```

Things I've already tried include:

```
    listView1.Update();
    listView1.BeginUpdate();
    ...
    listView1.EndUpdate();
    listView1.Refresh();
    listView1.Clear();
    listView1.RedrawItems(0,i,t/f);
    this.Update();
    this.Refresh();
```

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

More Code:

FormA setting up reference in formB:

```
    myNewForm.getForm = this;
```

FormB's reference to formA:

```
    private mainForm myForm = new mainForm();
    public mainForm getForm
    {
        get { return myForm; }
        set { myForm = value; }
    }
```

FormB calling FormA's function:

```
    myForm.forceAdd(accountBox.Text.ToString(), usernameBox.Text.ToString(), passwordBox.Text.ToString());
```

Is this an instance where I need to do an "invoke/delegate" ?

Edit 2:

Sorry I wasn't clear enough, FormB calls `FormA::populateList()`, I put Console output in the function to confirm this, it successfully adds items to the data set but just wont refresh the list. Its like it *knows* that this is an outside form that just wont let it refresh.

I also made populateList public, didnt work

Visual studios wont let me call `pupulateList()` from `(mainForm)this.Parent.` even after caling `myNewForm.ShowDialog(this);` do I have to include something or pass it some other way?

my reference to formA through `myForm` works, just not with updating lists..?

Edit 3:
This doesnt work either:

```
((mainForm)this.Parent).populateList();
```

Comment: include code in `formB` that is calling the function in `formA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FormB will have to have a reference to the instance of FormA. You can pass this reference to FormB when the insert button is clicked:

in FormA

```
FormB PWDForm= new FormB();
FormB.ShowDialog(this);
```

Next on FormB you can access FormA like this:

```
(FormA)this.Parent.populateList();
```